# What is tag reputation?

Tags: support, tags, reputation

When I earn some reputation, I get this message:

[image]

Furthermore in my `Tags` tab, I can see some numbers near tags:

[image]

But it's not clear to me. What is 42 and 10? And what is tag reputation?

Comment: Just hover over the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [`tags`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1723695/g4s8?tab=tags) section, when you hover on the 42 and 10 you can see the self-described tool-tip for the numbers.

> [image: tags section]

[`42`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1723695+%5Bc%23%5D+is%3Aanswer) - > You received 42 upvotes for the C# tag answers

[`10`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1723695+[c%23]) - > Total number of posts (question/answers) you posted on the C# tag.